# Two definitions of conormal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, symplectic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a smooth manifold and $f: Z \to X$ is an immersion with transverse self-intersection. I've seen (e.g. [here](http://www.math.duke.edu/~ng/math/papers/kch-survey-v2.2.pdf)) the conormal bundle to $Z$ in $T^* X$ defined as

**Definition A:** $\quad L_Z := \{(x,\alpha) \in T^*X \mid x \in Z, \, \alpha(v) =0 \text{ for all } v \in T_x Z \}\subset T^*X.$

> **Q1:** The space $L_Z$ is an *embedded* submanifold of $T^* X$. How can you see that it is embedded above self-intersection points of $Z$?

(If $x$ is a self-intersection point, $T_x Z$ is not defined, so I assume "$\alpha( v)=0 \text{ for all } v \in T_x Z$" means $\alpha \big( df_z (v) \big)=0$ for all $v \in T_z Z$ such that $f(z)=x$. Equivalently, $\alpha(\gamma'(0))=0$ for smooth curves $\gamma: (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to X$ with image in $f(Z)$. Note that $\alpha$ must be zero if $x$ is a transverse self-intersection point.)

The above definition is something of a "forgetful" conormal bundle, as it is essentially determined by the image $f(Z)$. If we have access to $f$ itself, it seems more natural to me to define the conormal bundle as a subbundle of the pullback of $T^* X \to X$ by $f$:

**Definition B:** $\quad N^*_f(Z):= \{ (z,\alpha) \in Z \times T^* X \mid \alpha \in T^*_{f(z)} X \text{ such that } \alpha\big( df_z (v)\big)=0 \text{ for all } v \in T_z Z\}. 
$

There's an obvious map $F: N^*_f(Z)\to T^*X$ which is an immersion (resp. embedding) if and only if $f$ is an immersion (resp. embedding). And $F(N_f^*(Z))=L_Z$ if $f$ is an embedding, but not if $f$ has transverse self-intersection points.

> **Q2:** Which (if either) of these two definitions is the standard definition of the conormal bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal bundle $N$ to $f$ is the quotient bundle  defined by the exact sequence of vector bundles on $Z$:
$$0\to T_Z\to f^*T_X\to N\to 0$$ The conormal bundle is just the dual bundle $N^*$ on $Z$, and it is indeed a subbundle of $f^*(T^*_X)$
This is equivalent to your definition B, up to the identification of the dual of a quotient bundle with the annihilator of the subbundle:  $N^*\simeq T_Z^\circ$
 Consideration of $f(Z)$ or "transverse self-intersection" is irrelevant and confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the additional perspective.  The first definition came from a survey by Lenny Ng; it's at http://www.math.duke.edu/~ng/math/papers/kch-survey-v2.2.pdf, for now.  It seems odd to mention the specific condition of self-transverse immersions if there isn't an interpretation in which it's valid.